# Viewing localStorage on ios and android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, webview

Is it possible to access my app's localStorage in other way then via this app?

I am making an app which uses localStorage and I want to be sure there are no possibilities that someone can access my data.

Thank you for your attention and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap applications are executed on a UIWebView, which uses WebKit engine for all the web-related stuff. 
All the navigation data, such as the local storage, caches and so on are stored in the app's data store (a sandbox) and thus can't be accessed from any other apps unless you provide the methods to do so, ie: shared keychains, URIs and so on.

This is built into the iOS security system and there isn't an official way of accessing the data via the public APIS (which doesn't mean it's totally secure). If you are storing sensible information that you don't want to be accessed you should always encrypt such data. Refer to this [document](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Platform-Security) if you need more info on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

By default no one can access the data stored in your app except your app itself. In the info.plist file you can add an entry

`Application supports iTunes file sharing`

If you add this field in your info.plist and set it to YES, only in that case the user can access the data stored in the documents directory by connecting the device to the iTunes.